# Load custom page templates in WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have several custom page templates in my theme. But I want to hide a few with a plugin, and only show the custom home page template on the page that has been set as the front page "is_front_page" or "is_home". This is what I am using in my plugin to stop some of the page templates from showing up.

This is for a large multisite where there are two tiers of sites, one gets the full set of features, and the other a stunted set. I have everything working as I need except for this.

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'je_remove_page_template' );
  function je_remove_page_template( $pages_templates ) {
  unset( $pages_templates['page-topimage.php'] );
  unset( $pages_templates['page-home.php'] );
  return $pages_templates;
}
```

The code above works totally fine, but I need a conditional in there to show the page-home.php when the page has been set to the home page. I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :

    add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'je_remove_page_template' );
    function je_remove_page_template( $pages_templates ) {
    unset( $pages_templates['page-topimage.php'] );
    return $pages_templates;
    }

    else :

    function je_remove_page_template( $pages_templates ) {
    unset( $pages_templates['page-topimage.php'] );
    unset( $pages_templates['page-home.php'] );
    return $pages_templates;
    }

endif;
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I am trying to stop the custom page templates from showing up in the drop down list on the edit screen in the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

One, it appears you've only added the [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) call to the [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)'s `true` condition, that's probably part of it.

Second, you should *not* be defining and/or redefining functions inside `if` statements!

Third, for WordPress specifically, with it's [Action Hook and Filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) system, it's generally considered a best practice to add the filters and actions at all times, and run `if/else` or abort type statements inside the function to allow for easier extensibility.

## Edit:

Based on some clarification, I understand a bit better. You need to get the ID of the page that's set to the front page, which is stored as an option named `page_on_front` in the options table. The `is_front_page()` function will only work in the scope of the current `$wp_query` loop.

I think this would solve it for you. Run the `je_remove_page_template` function on the [`theme_page_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) filter, and check the current page's ID against the one stored in the `page_on_front` option:

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'je_remove_page_template' );
function je_remove_page_template( $pages_templates ){
    unset( $pages_templates['page-topimage.php'] );

    $home_page_id = absint( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
    $this_page_id = get_the_ID();

    // If this isn't the home page, remove `page-home`
    if( $this_page_id != $home_page_id ){
        unset( $pages_templates['page-home.php'] );
    }

    return $pages_templates;
}
```

Also of note would be that [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) is different than [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) - make sure you're using the correct one! (I believe you are, as generally IFP is what people want)

Comment: thanks for this but it doesn't work for me. From what I've read I think IFP needs some kind of loop or another hook to get it to load.

Comment: Can you do `var_dump( is_front_page() );` in that same function and see what it returns on various pages? Also, is this is for the post_type `page`, correct?

Comment: Yes for post_type page. Because this is working with the page templates on the page edit screen it needs something extra to figure out if IFP is there or not.

Comment: var_dump returns false on all pages, even on the page that I have set as the front page.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I didn't quite understand the question I suppose. But yes you're right, `is_front_page()` and similar functions only work in the scope of the current loop seeing if you're actively on the front page of the site. I've updated to answer to show you how to compare the current page's ID to that of the one that's set to the front page. That should work better!

Comment: Thanks you! Yes this works perfectly. Sorry I wasn't more clear on my original question. I re-read it and I made a comment to try to clarify for anyone else looking at this in the future.